# How can I restrict gestures are working only draw line area itself in Xamarin.Ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

[image]

What I have tried is

```
  CAShapeLayer shapeLayer = new CAShapeLayer();

  shapeLayer.Path = new CGPath();

  shapeLayer.Path.AddLines(new CGPoint [] { startingPoint, endingPoint});

  shapeLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;

  shapeLayer.LineWidth = (System.nfloat)3.0;

  shapeLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;

  var width = Math.Abs(latestPoint.X - initioalPoint.X) + initioalPoint.X;

  var height = Math.Abs(latestPoint.Y - initioalPoint.Y) + initioalPoint.Y;

  var padding = 10;

  shapeLayer.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, width + padding - 2, height + padding - 2);


  var view = new UIView();

  view.Layer.AddSubLayer(shapeLayer);


  CanvasView canvasDrawLine = new CanvasView(subView);

  canvasDrawLine.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, width + padding, height + padding[![enter image description here][1]][1]);

  Public Class CanvasView : UIView
 {
    public CanvasView(drawline)
    {
       drawLine.ClipsToBounds = true;

       var width = Math.Abs(endingPoint.X - initioalPoint.X) + initioalPoint.X;

       var height = Math.Abs(endingPoint.Y - initioalPoint.Y) + initioalPoint.Y;

        var padding = 10;

        drawLine.Frame = new CGRect(5,5, width + padding, height + padding);

        this.AddSubview(drawLine);

        setUpGestures();
    }
 }

 scrollView.AddSubview(canvasDrawLine );
```

when I set the width and height of the frame default, my gestures not working properly, for example If I have apply a pan gesture to the draw line even out of the draw line also pan gesture is working.How can I restrict all gestures are working only draw line area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate bounds of your area covered by line :

```
CoreGraphics.CGPoint initialPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(1, 2);
            CoreGraphics.CGPoint latestPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(1, 2);
            var width = Math.Abs(latestPoint.X - initialPoint.X);
            var height = Math.Abs(latestPoint.X - initialPoint.X);
            var padding = 10;

            subView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, width+padding, height+padding);
```

I have created sample code with simple view controller class -- Have assigned red colour to view containing line. And its working perfect. gesture recogniser is working on red part only --where line is.

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        CGPoint initioalPoint = new CGPoint(12, 12);
        CGPoint latestPoint = new CGPoint(80, 45);
        var shapeLayer = new CAShapeLayer();

        shapeLayer.Path = new CGPath();

        shapeLayer.Path.AddLines(new CGPoint[] { initioalPoint, latestPoint });

        shapeLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;

        shapeLayer.LineWidth = (System.nfloat)3.0;

        shapeLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;

        var subView = new UIView();
        var width = Math.Abs(latestPoint.X - initioalPoint.X) + initioalPoint.X;
        var height = Math.Abs(latestPoint.Y - initioalPoint.Y) + initioalPoint.Y;
        var padding = 10;

        subView.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, width + padding, height + padding);
        subView.Layer.AddSublayer(shapeLayer);
        shapeLayer.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, width + padding-2, height + padding-2);
        subView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;


        var mainView = new UIView();

        mainView.Frame = new CGRect(40, 40, width + padding+200, height + padding+200);
        mainView.AddSubview(subView);
        mainView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;

        this.View.AddSubview(mainView);
        UITapGestureRecognizer tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
        tap.AddTarget((obj) => {new  UIAlertView("tapped","",null,"ok",null).Show();});
        subView.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
        //UITapGestureRecognizer tap  = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() => Console.WriteLine("tap"));


        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

///To check if Touch Point is inside Given Polygon::

```
    CGPoint pt1 = new CGPoint(initioalPoint.X - 50, initioalPoint.Y - 50);
    CGPoint pt2 = new CGPoint(initioalPoint.X + 50, initioalPoint.Y - 50);
    CGPoint pt3 = new CGPoint(latestPoint.X - 50, latestPoint.Y + 50);
    CGPoint pt4 = new CGPoint(latestPoint.X + 50, latestPoint.Y + 50);

    UIBezierPath path = new UIBezierPath();
    path.MoveTo(pt1);
    path.AddLineTo(pt2);
    path.AddLineTo(pt3);
    path.AddLineTo(pt4);
    path.AddLineTo(pt1);

    if (!path.ContainsPoint(ToucPoint))
        return;
```

Comment: I have followed what you said but not working, I am try to adjust the padding and x,y positions also but not luck. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have tried following code but gestures are working out of draw line.

Comment: I cant understand what mistake you are making, but created sample code  -- you can use it or logic from it to set frame.

Comment: I am updated the code what I have actually tried. please tell me where I have done mistake.

Comment: I have update the screen shot for what I have got after trying above code.

Comment: whats problem with what you got above? Thats correct actually.

Comment: Now, If don't want action on point outside line, You must handle that in Gesture Event. PointF offset = recognizer.TranslationInView(subview); ...now check that point is inside required rectangle.

Comment: I have tried but gestures are working throughout frame(total gray color area) but I want to work gestures only that I have red color rounded in draw line only.

Comment: So go for checking touch points..if that falls within given area -- You cant define Gesture to this kind of shape.  In gesture recogniser, check touch points fall within that area or not.

Comment: Can we set CGRect is this kind of shape?. If we have possibility to set this kind of shape, I think problem is fixed. If we can limit touch area then also can't limit exact draw line area only gestures are working.

Comment: If we take InitioalPoint.X = 100 and FinalPoint.X = 200. There X position will be not constant, it will possibility to increase or decrease position. If we restrict the gestures between these two points also we can't archive what we required because between these two points also some empty place is present in that also gestures are working but what we actually required is gestures are not working where empty places are there. It would work only exact that draw line area.

Comment: create rectangle --- point1 = (initialX-50,initialY-50), point2=(initial+50,initialy-50) ,point3= (endX- 50,endY+50),point4 = (endX+50,endY+50) .... Now check if touch point is insde these 4 points.--

Comment: I have added code to check if your touch point is inside your required area in answer

Comment: Yes, it's work's fine now. Thank you very much for your cooperation but gestures are working some little bit outside in drawline at someplace and gestures are not working exact draw line area at some place.